# Sum overlapping dates in Postgresql Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to find all listings that overlap a given date range, and its not quite working as expected. I have an 'UnavailableDate' model, with an id, start_date, end_date and listing_id. What I have so far is:

```
   @unavailable_listings = UnavailableDate.find_by_sql("SELECT listing_id, SUM((LEAST(extract(epoch FROM end_date), #{check_out.to_i}) - GREATEST(extract(epoch FROM start_date), #{check_in.to_i}))/86400) AS overlap FROM unavailable_dates GROUP BY listing_id")
```

This is working to an extent, although when a listing has more than one 'UnavailableDate' the SUM doesn't work correctly. However, what I really need to do is add a WHERE clause, so only those listings with an 'overlap' greater than X are found. What is the best way to approach this?

Basically, I want this query to result in an array of listing IDs, which I can then use in my main Thinking Sphinx  query in the :without clause (to remove all listings which are unavailable for more than 50% of the search dates). Seems like a rather inefficient way of doing it but I think its my only option

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for whether two date ranges overlap is simple that the end date of range 1 is greater than or equal to the start date of range 2, and the start date of range 1 is less than or equal to the end date of range 2.

```
where range1.end_date   >= range2.start_date and
      range1.start_date <= range2.end_date
```

The >= and <= may end up being > or < depending on your definition of range boundaries.

Working out the size of the overlap can be done with:

```
least(range1.end_date, range2.end_date) - greatest(range1.start_date, range2.start_date)
```

Adjust the function calls to whatever your RDBMS uses to find earliest and latest dates, and depending on your definitions of start and end date you might need to adjust that value by a constant.

Comment: Thanks David, that helps, but I really need to alter the 'where' statement to only find records where the size of the overlap is greater than a constant. Ie if the search dates span 14 days, I want to find all results with more than a 7 day overlap.

Comment: That should just require turning the statement that work out the number of days overlap into a predicate: blah blah > 7

Comment: What exactly is a predicate? I have the following, and it says the column 'overlap' doesn't exist -        @unavailable_rooms = UnavailableDate.find_by_sql("SELECT listing_id, SUM((LEAST(extract(epoch FROM end_date), #{check_out.to_i}) - GREATEST(extract(epoch FROM start_date), #{check_in.to_i}))/86400) AS overlap FROM unavailable_dates WHERE #{check_out.to_i} >= extract(epoch FROM start_date) and #{check_in.to_i} <= extract(epoch FROM end_date) and overlap > 5 GROUP BY listing_id")

Comment: Sorry my bad, got it working with this: @unavailable_rooms = UnavailableDate.find_by_sql("SELECT listing_id FROM unavailable_dates WHERE (LEAST(extract(epoch FROM end_date), #{check_out.to_i}) - GREATEST(extract(epoch FROM start_date), #{check_in.to_i}))/86400 > 5 GROUP BY listing_id"). Thanks for your help!